# Browser shows 404 despite route:list showing route

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, routes

I am trying to access a route that lives in api.php file, but when i try to open it or do a fetch call this happens:
[image: 404 page]

also, i tried route:clear, and route:list gives me follwing output:

```
  GET|HEAD  api/videos ............................................................ VideoController@index  
  POST      api/videos ............................................................ VideoController@store  
  GET|HEAD  api/videos/random .................................................... VideoController@random  
  GET|HEAD  api/videos/{video} ..................................................... VideoController@show  
  PUT       api/videos/{video} ................................................... VideoController@update  
  DELETE    api/videos/{video} ................................................... VideoController@delete 
// sanctum routes
// other routes
```

## api.php

```
    use App\Http\Controllers\VideoController;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

    Route::prefix('videos')->group(function() {
        Route::controller(VideoController::class)->group(function () {
            // more routes
            Route::get('/random', 'random');
            // more routes
        });
    });
```

## Video Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\VideoStoreRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\VideoUpdateRequest;
use App\Http\Resources\VideoCollection;
use App\Http\Resources\VideoResource;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Video;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class VideoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function random(Request $request)
    {
        return Video::inRandomOrder()->take(10)->get();
    }

    // more actions...

}
```

## Relevant Information

- Laravel 9
- PHP 8.1

Comment: Clearly `GET|HEAD  api/videos/{video}` is taking precedence. Move `api/videos/random` above it.